# How to make a jar file of a single class?

Tags: java, class, jar

I have a Java project with multiple classes but I only want my jar file to have one class.

How can I do it?

Comment: Create just one class. Or you mean you want all the other classes merged into a single class file? If it's the latter, what for?

Comment: I really just want one class because I will need it in a node js project

Comment: Oh, so you mean that from that whole project made of `ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC` you want a jar containing `ClassB` only, for example? If that's the case, does `ClassB` depend on other classes? Because if that's the case you'll need to bring the whole dependencies hierarchy in the JAR anyway. If not, just make another project containing only `ClassB` and make a JAR out of that.

Comment: Basically I have a class that implements CustomTaskChange. That class is inherited by class A,B and C. What I want to do is have separated Jar files for class A, B and C(three jars)

Comment: Why? You will need all those JAR files at the target for all those classes to execute. Why do you want 1 JAR instead of four (not three)?

Comment: I need to use them in a liquibase customChange in Node js

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you don't.

If you need your JAR to contain just one class, then your source code should be built around that.

Comment: So should I create a new project and move that class to the new project?

Comment: I think it would make sense to do so given the context and your requirements - which I'd recommend including in the original post :)